# Installing Charlock_Holmes - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and installing gems through the terminal. I'm having a bit of trouble installing charlock_holmes. When I try to install, I am met with this big error, which I am unable to make heads or tails of:

```
ryan@ubuntu:~/Desktop/linguist$ sudo gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.7.3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for main() in -licuuc... yes
checking for main() in -licudata... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling converter.c
In file included from converter.c:2:0:
common.h:23:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-     function]
static VALUE charlock_new_str(const char *str, size_t len)
          ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-    function]
static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
          ^
compiling encoding_detector.c
In file included from encoding_detector.c:2:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_enc_str’ defined but not used [-    Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void     *encoding)
          ^
compiling ext.c
In file included from ext.c:1:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_enc_str’ defined but not used [-    Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void   *encoding)
          ^
common.h:23:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-    function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str(const char *str, size_t len)
          ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-    function]
static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
          ^
compiling transliterator.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [transliterator.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-    0.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
```

I am really stuck as to do what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have the `g++`  compiler installed. Install it via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Error log, it seems that g++ compiler is not installed. Please install with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

And then run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev   
sudo gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.7.3'
```

**NOTE**: `libicu-dev` is pre-rack dependancy to `charlock_holmes`

Hopefully this will help!